# Any pitfalls in powering the same dc load with the same dc source but with two sets of wires?

Tags: power-supply, dc

So I've got a solenoid valve opened and closed using a relay switch (controlled by an Arduino) upon the +ve side. I would also like to give this valve a separate power connection to open and close it with a simple spst switch without going through the Arduino. Just want to know, is it a good idea? If both switches (the relay and the spst) open together by mistake, any harm in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this no problem: -

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f0Z2uR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

> *If both switches (the relay and the spst) open together by mistake,
> any harm in it?*

Providing you use the diodes to catch the back emfs from the inductive parts there are no electrical problems. As to whether turning the relay off via a mechanical switch or a relay has operational problems for the wider system, I cannot say; that's your call.

> *I would also like to give this valve a separate power connection to
> open and close it with a simple spst switch without going through the
> Arduino*

- If the Arduino is activating the relay then the manual switch can do nothing about that situation.
- If Arduino is not activating the relay then, the manual switch can activate the solenoid

So, if you want this to be different i.e. the manual switch can always deactivate the solenoid, the manual switch needs to be wired in series with the relay contact.

However if you want both Arduino and manual switch to be able to open and close the solenoid then, there is added complication but, it can be done. You need to say what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Using a manual switch in parallel with a relay is fine, assuming they are both rated for the current and voltage they will be switching.

In your case, there is a particular concern, which is that the load is inductve. Inductive loads, if not properly "snubbered" may cause arcing in switches or relays, causing them to fail.

If the current through the switch or relay is DC, you can use a diode, or diode and resistor pair, or diode, zener diode, and resistor, as a snubber.

Answer (score 2):

If you connect the switch and relay contact in parallel you will only be able to override the Arduino in turning the valve 'on'. If you connect the contacts in series then you will only be able to override the Arduino in turning the valve 'off'.

If you need to control it completely you could use a 3-position ['on-on-on' toggle switch](https://www.nkkswitches.com/pdf/Mseries_Gold%20_Black_Toggles.pdf) with centre position Arduino, and the other two positions UP for override "ON" and DOWN for  override "OFF".

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZtrGH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]